# Selenium 'ant run-demo-in-parallel' command failure?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid, automated-tests, remote-control

I'm trying to run the Selenium Grid Demo successfully but I'm having a problem.

I have the hub set up correctly with 4 localhost Remote Controls.  When I try to run them in parallel I get the following result:

```
 [java]
[java] ===============================================
[java] Selenium Grid Demo In Parallel
[java] Total tests run: 4, Failures: 4, Skips: 0
[java] ===============================================
[java]
```

[BUILD FAILED
:\Selenium Grid\selenium-grid-1.0.8-bin\selenium-grid-1.0.8\build.xml:137: Java
returned: 1
Total time: 1 second
:\Selenium Grid\selenium-grid-1.0.8-bin\selenium-grid-1.0.8>]

I have the latest on all version of:

Selenium Webdriver
Remote Control
Selenium Grid
Apache Ant

Is there  a workaround?

Comment: EDIT:  I get that result after I enter "ant run-demo-in-parallel" in the selenium directory. I'm following direction from    http://selenium-grid.seleniumhq.org/run_the_demo.html

Comment: What version of firefox are you using?

Comment: I'm using Firefox Version 12.0.

Comment: As mentioned in my answer, selenium grid 1.x development is not happening now. FF 12 is not supported in selenium grid 1.8. You need to use Grid 2.0

Comment: I cannot find any good walkthrough's in setting up Grid 2.0 though.  Do you have any knowledge of any A.J.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selenium Grid 1.x is no longer supported. See the notification [here](https://github.com/nirvdrum/selenium-grid) . Per Kevin -

**Selenium Grid 1 End of Lifed**

Please note that Selenium Grid 1 is no longer an active project. This repository only exists as a historical artifact. All new work has been going into Selenium Grid 2, which has been integrated directly with the Selenium project and source tree. Please note we have taken every reasonable measure to ensure that Selenium Grid 2 is backwards compatible with Selenium Grid 1, so there's virtually no reason at all to use Selenium Grid 1.

You can try out the new and better **Grid 2.0**. Help and documentation to get you started are [here](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/Grid2)